# How to prevent the creation of multiple entries for requests that are being processed simultaneously in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Laravel has the eloquent method:

```
firstOrCreate
```

to return a database entry if it already exists.

If two users open a page at the same time two datasets are entered in the database.

```php
Route::get('/some-route/{param}', function($param) {

    $data = Model::firstOrCreate(
        ['col', $param],
        ['col', $param]
    );

    return view('some-view', [
        'data' => $data
    ]);

});
```

How can I prevent the creation of multiple entries?

Comment: Apply a unique index on the database column ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet I already have an index on the database column.